# Problems finding pcap.h and linking

Tags: c, linux, fedora, libpcap

I'm working on Fedora 17 and I want to program with libpcap. The problem is that my computer isn't finding pcap.h, which is really wierd since I've installed libpcap and libpcap-devel. Also wireshark and snort works on my station which I believe uses that library. So when I compile my code with ...

```
#include <pcap.h>
... Code
```

And use gcc my_file.c -lpcap, I get compiler errors that say ... can't find pcap.h. Whats odd is that I see my libpcap.so files in /libraries/ directory. I've done ..

yum install libpcap
and 
yum install libpcap-devel

I don't know why Fedora is doing this to me.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to specify the folder where the headers are installed, for example:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/pcap my_file.c -lpcap
```

Try `locate pcap.h` to find the right directory to use with the `-I` switch.

Comment: Ya it doesn't seem like libpcap and libpcap-devel come with the necessary files that I need. I think I have to find all the individual header files.

Answer (score 16):

Your library might be missing, install it and link it

```
yum install libpcap-devel
```

In your makefile add:

```
-L/usr/lib -lpcap
```

Comment: OP states `libpcap-devel` is installed (along with `libpcap`)!

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
~$ whereis pcap
```

Then as mata said

```
gcc -lpcap -I{path} file.c
```

where `{path}` is the path that `whereis` gave you, you will choose the one with the pcap.h substring at the end (without the pcap.h part).

Comment: If you're frustrated and do not see a solution to your problem, you can make one more effort to make sure you installed the library properly. `~$ find /usr/ -iname '*.c' -or '*.h' | grep -i pcap`

Comment: @Dirk I believe because of my first comment, also look at the date of the answer.

Comment: @Dirk Nevertheless, you can use, `which` or  maybe `apropos` instead of `whereis`, basically they serve the same purpose as `whereis`. Please note that, `pcap` may be installed somewhere outside the search PATH. The `-L` option might not work as intended if you don't know where to look, so you may want to use `find` to locate where the library actually resides.

Comment: @yeyo, are you mixing up executables and binaries in your explanations? Again: there is no executable `pcap` in a standard distribution with Fedora, AFAIK.

Comment: @Dirk I have not been able to find the place where I stated  `pcap` is an executable, I believe you are misinterpreting my answer. I'm suggesting a brute-force approach to find where the pcap library was installed, when conventional methods fail.

Comment: The point is that `which pcap` will look for an executable `pcap` in the directories defined by `$PATH`. But you are right, I misinterpreted your answer, it is correct. What is the reference to "mata"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97305/discussion-between-dirk-and-yeyo).

Comment: @yeyo Your comment helped my find it.

and FWIW, I had to modifiy your one liner a little bit to run on Ubuntu 16.04
`find . -iname '*.c' -or -iname '*.h' | grep -i pcap`

Comment: @GandhiGandhi Keep in mind  `.` is a shorthand for the `current working directory`, with your version, the result one gets will depend on the directory you are in at the time of execution.

Answer (score 0):

To execute the program in c++:

for c++ program

```
 g++ program_name.cpp -lpcap
```